# c# Random class error

Tags: c#, class, random

I have the following script:

```
int n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
var r = new Random();
Console.WriteLine(r.Next(1, n));
```

And I got this error message:

> 'Random.Random' does not contain a definition for 'Next' and no extension method 'Next' accepting a first argument of type 'Random.Random' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Where did I go wrong?
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: You are referring to `Random.Random` not `System.Random`.

Comment: @Rosdi I doubt that. OP most likely hit the wrong context menu after pasting this code and generated a new, empty Random class in their project's namespace. The more general case of that happening is very well documented here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have another class `Random` in your project. Use [`System.Random`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) or rename the other:

```
System.Random r = new System.Random();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have another class named Random in your assembly, and it doesn't have a Next() method. Try this:

```
    int n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    var r = new System.Random();
    Console.WriteLine(r.Next(1, n));
```